# How to initiate a function using data(){} but not mounted(){} while using vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

This works, but I need to use `mounted(){}` to initiate the function which I think can be avoided but not sure how.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        domains: [],
      }
    },

    methods: {
      fetchDomains() {
        let _this = this;

        api._get({url: 'api/domains'})
          .then(function (response) {
            _this.domains = response.data;
          })
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.fetchDomains()
    }
  }
</script>
```

This code doesn't work, but I like to do something like this. Initiating the function in `data(){}` itself.

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        domains: this.fetchDomains(),
      }
    },

    methods: {
      fetchDomains() {
        let data = [];

        api._get({url: 'api/domains'})
          .then(function (response) {
            data = response.data;
          })

        return data
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Decade Moon that your first approach is the better way to do it (though you could use `created` instead of `mounted`).

The reason your second approach doesn't work is that you return an array and then replace the local variable's value with a different array. What you need to do is populate the array you returned.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {item: this.getItem()}
  },
  methods: {
    getItem() {
      let val = [];
      setTimeout(() => {
        const result = ['first','second','third'];
        val.push(...result);
      }, 800);
      return val;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">{{item}}</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first code snippet is the correct way to do it.

You can't initialize `domains` with the data from the API response because it is an async operation which may or may not be resolved successfully at some point in the future, well after the component is mounted. You might also want to do other things like keeping track of the async operation with a `loading` property which you set to `true` for the duration of the request.

Your component will initially be in a loading state which does not yet have any `domains` data, and you need to account for this. Show a loading spinner or something during this time.

Comment: Correct advice, not quite technically correct answer. His 2nd method could work because it returns a variable that will asynchronously be populated, but the trick is to populate array he has it set to, and not replace it.

Answer (score 1):

I might be deviating slightly from the question (since it explicitly mentions the `data` property), but I think this might be helpful. Personally, if I want to provide some data with more complex logic I use the `computed` property. This is great in my opinion and you can read more about it in [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). The problem in this case is that it doesn't work entirely as expected with asynchronous operations...

However, there is a lovely little module called vue-async-computed which can be found [here](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed). It solves this specific problem by providing an `asyncComputed` property and keeps the code really clean!